# Passar dados arquivo CSV para array em R (BARPLOT)

Tags: r

Preciso plotar um gráfico em R importando um arquivo csv. Após fazer a importação do csv e chamar o barplot ele acusa que a variavel que eu importei o csv não é um vetor. Então, como eu transformo em um vetor para utilizar no barplot? Tbm gostaria de usar o header de de cada coluna pra nomear a respectiva barra, tem como? O arquivo é simples; só tem 2 linhas, uma com as headers e outra com os valores correspondentes.

Tentei assim primeiro:

```
    > data <- read.csv("tabela4_p2.csv", header = TRUE)
    > names <- c("Bancos", "Arborização", "EstComerc", "CasaResid","EdifResid", "ConstAband")

    barplot(as.integer(data$Bancos, data$Arborização, data$EstComerc, data$CasaResid, data$EdifResid, data$ConstAband), names.arg = names)
```

E deu isso aqui:

```
    Error in barplot.default(as.integer(data$Bancos, data$Arborização,data$EstComerc,: 
    número incorreto de nomes
```

Depois usei assim:

```
    barplot(data, names.arg = names)
```

E deu:

```
    Error in barplot.default(data, names.arg = names) : 
    'height' deve ser um vetor ou uma matriz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que o que você quer é algo deste tipo:

```
x <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)
names(x) <- c("a", "b", "c")
barplot(height = as.numeric(x[1,]), names.arg = names(x))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que:

```
> as.integer(1,2,3)
[1] 1
```

Ou seja é um escalar e não um vetor. O seu código poderia funcionar fazendo:

```
barplot(as.integer(c(data$Bancos, data$Arborização, data$EstComerc, data$CasaResid, data$EdifResid, data$ConstAband)), names.arg = names)
```

Veja que dentro do `as.integer` coloquei a função `c` que **c**oncatena os elementos, antes de você chamar o `as.integer`.

Comment: Retornou o seguinte:  ** Error in barplot.default(as.integer(c(data$Bancos, data$Arborização, data$EstComerc,  : 
  número incorreto de nomes **

Comment: sua base tem realmente uma linha e o mesmo numero de colunas que o vetor names?

Comment: A tabela é assim e fiz como tu colocou:
Bancos Arborização EstComerc CasaResid EdifResid ConstAband
  112       22       80          72            40              11

Comment: Eu tava fazendo coisa errada! Deu certo de mais! Vlw!